ASP.NET MVC images not displaying
I got app.UseStaticFiles(); in Program.CS
I got <img class="mini" src="/images/sweter.JPG"> in site html when debuging.
The file exists in wwwroot/images. But images is not rendering. I can go to URL localhost:4343/site.css and I get code from this file, when I'm going to localhost:4343/images/sweter.JPG image is not displaying too. The site is blank.
What is a problem?
I used @Url.Content("\~" + p.ImageSrc) in src attribute.
I'm searching in applicationhost.config and I got
<staticTypes>
<add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
</staticTypes>
<staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpeg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
</staticContent>
<add name="StaticFile" value="0" />

I check status code in browser and I got code 200 (OK), but the size of image is only about 135B. So image is not downloading from server.

I can't reproduce your issue in my side, According to your description, when going to localhost:4343/images/sweter.JPG, image is not displaying too, but site is blank. If you are using an incorrect, you shall get some other error instead of blank site. May I know whether you've tried to use another jpg file for testing?

Thank you for your confirmation about the test result. I also shared my troubleshoot plan below.

Firstly, I had a test in my side with image name sweter.JPG or sweter.jpg, and in my image url I test with src="/images/sweter.JPG" and src="/images/sweter.jpg" but all of them work well, in the meantime, OP confirmed that the request to the image gets 200 response, so that it is not related to case sensitive.
Another weird thing is that if the response is 200, the site should load the image, even if there's some other error, the site shouldn't be black, then I deduce it's resulted from that the image content is incomplete, corrupted, or it's serving an incorrect file. To verify this assumption, we can try to test with a new image and clean the project if required. According to OP's confiramtion, using another image could solve the issue.
